# Even after entering into viewDidLoad, the view controller`s view is not visible

Tags: iphone

There is a unique problem in my iPhone app that happens on a rare basis. I have a share button on screen which on being clicked opens up the share view controller screen responsible for facebook,twitter,sms and email sharing. Most of the time behaviour is good. But sometimes the share button stops working at all. The interesting thing in such cases is that on click of the button,flow goes into the action method of the button and subsequently into the viewDidLoad of my share view controller as well. But the share view controller screen does not appeaer. My button action method consists of the fllowing code :

```
 _shareViewController = [[ShareViewController alloc] init];

 NSLog(@"%d",[_shareViewController retainCount]);

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:self.shareViewController.view]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set frame for your view. so it's CGRectZero.
Try Add this.

```
    _shareViewController = [[ShareViewController alloc] init];

 NSLog(@"%d",[_shareViewController retainCount]);
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];

[window addSubview:self.shareViewController.view];
self.shareViewController.view.frame  = window.frame;
```

Comment: But if it was about CGRectZero,then the screen should nver have appeared. My problem is 95% of the time, on click of the button the share screen is visible and behaves properly. Only at rare times this happens. Also it`s very difficult to reproduce this as there is no pattern involved.